# Does stopping debug mode within using statement close the file stream?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-ziparchive

Just a thought that occurred when I was writing a zip extraction method.

I've got a using statement for the OpenRead method so the resources should be disposed once the statement has run though as we all know. However whilst writing the code, I was debugging and a couple of times, I've stopped debugging to alter some code within the using statement. When I've stopped debugging however, the using statement hasn't run through fully, therefore technically hasn't disposed/closed any resources.. Does Visual Studio do this automatically when you stop debugging?

Looked around briefly but can't find any hints. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 (Version 15.9.10) and .NET Framework (Version 4.7.03056)

```
        public void Decompress_SaveToFile(string zipFilePath, string directoryPath)
        {
            using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFilePath))
            {
                foreach(ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    if(File.Exists(directoryPath))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Decompressed file already exists.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        entry.ExtractToFile(directoryPath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I expect it to close all streams/resources but just curious.

Comment: The `using` statement is just a glorified `try-finally` block where all the dispose logic is written in the `finally` block, so regardless if it throws an exception it will dispose the resource properly.

Comment: It is not a problem.  It is the job of the operating system to close any remaining opened file handles at program termination.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee That is incorrect: when a process is terminated, it won't execute any further instructions, including any `finally` blocks. The `finally` block will only be executed if the OP chooses "Detach", not "Stop".

Answer (score 2):

When you stop a debugger, you're essentially killing a process. You asked it to **stop** - you didn't ask it to politely unwind everything, which could execute arbitrary amounts of code.

When you hit stop in a debugger, the only expectation you should have is that the process *probably* exits. Nothing more is promised.

This is the same as with regular execution; `using` is a `try`/`finally`, and there is no **guarantee** that a `finally` will execute; if someone kills the process: it won't execute. If someone unplugs the power cable: it won't execute. Etc. `finally` will only execute during a graceful normal execution path (whether through success or an exception).

Comment: Thanks Marc, that's a well explained answer. So based on your answer, I'm assuming that its a bad habit that I should stop?

Comment: @DylanDelport that really depends on what your code is doing :) in most cases, it really won't matter - tearing down the process will release any locked files, etc, and usually anything in your debug bin folder ... doesn't matter if it gets corrupted. If you *absolutely* need to run your `finally` statements (at least, as much as is possible) then indeed: don't stop the debugger. But to emphasize: it is a tiny minority of cases where this would matter.